# OpenCL beignet 1.3.1-2 fails with the error: drm_intel_gem_bo_context_exec() failed: No space left on device

Tags: opencl, intel, beignet

I recently have restarted to program in OpenCL and faced a beignet related error when I run the program like below:

```
/*
  Hello World for OpenCL

  How to compile:
  : c++ hello.cpp -lOpenCL
*/

#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS

#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  cl_int ret;
  cl_platform_id plat_id = NULL;
  cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
  cl_device_id dev_id = NULL;
  cl_uint ret_num_devices;
  cl_context context = NULL;
  cl_command_queue queue = NULL; 
  cl_program program = NULL;

  char const * kernel_cl=R"(
kernel void hello() {
  printf("Hello! OpenCL!");
}
)";
  size_t kernel_cl_len = strlen(kernel_cl);

  ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &plat_id, &ret_num_platforms);
  ret = clGetDeviceIDs(plat_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL,
                       1, &dev_id, &ret_num_devices);
  context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &dev_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);
  queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, dev_id, 0, &ret);

  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
                                      (const char**)&kernel_cl,
                                      (const size_t*)&kernel_cl_len,
                                      &ret);

  ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &dev_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  cl_kernel ker_hello;
  ker_hello = clCreateKernel(program, "hello", &ret);
  cl_event event;
  ret = clEnqueueTask(queue, ker_hello, 0, NULL, &event);
  ret = clWaitForEvents(1, &event);
  ret = clReleaseKernel(ker_hello);

  ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
  ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
  ret = clReleaseContext(context);
}
```

It fails with the error, `drm_intel_gem_bo_context_exec() failed: No space left on device`.

My compile environment is gcc 7.1.1. and OpenCl Platform is beignet 1.3.1-2 which is installed from Arch GNU+Linux packages. The using OpenCL device is Intel HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2. And Here's my `clinfo` result:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing
  Platform Extensions function suffix             Intel
drm_intel_gem_bo_context_exec() failed: No space left on device

  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
  Device Vendor                                   Intel
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Driver Version                                  1.3
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 beignet 1.3
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Available                                Yes
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               16
  Max clock frequency                             1000MHz
  Device Partition                                (core)
    Max number of sub-devices                     1
    Supported partition types                     None, None, None
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             512x512x512
  Max work group size                             512
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Linker Available                                Yes
  Preferred work group size multiple              16
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 8       
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 0 / 8        (n/a)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               0 / 2        (n/a)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (n/a)
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (n/a)
  Address bits                                    32, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2147483648 (2GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1610612736 (1.5GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              Yes
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       1024 bits (128 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        Read/Write
  Global Memory cache size                        8192 (8KiB)
  Global Memory cache line                        64 bytes
  Image support                                   Yes
    Max number of samplers per kernel             16
    Max size for 1D images from buffer            65536 pixels
    Max 1D or 2D image array size                 2048 images
    Base address alignment for 2D image buffers   4096 bytes
    Pitch alignment for 2D image buffers          1 bytes
    Max 2D image size                             8192x8192 pixels
    Max 3D image size                             8192x8192x2048 pixels
    Max number of read image args                 128
    Max number of write image args                8
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               65536 (64KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        134217728 (128MiB)
  Max number of constant args                     8
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Prefer user sync for interop                    Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      80ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            Yes
  printf() buffer size                            1048576 (1024KiB)
  Built-in kernels                                __cl_copy_region_align4;__cl_copy_region_align16;__cl_cpy_region_unalign_same_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_dst_offset;__cl_copy_region_unalign_src_offset;__cl_copy_buffer_rect;__cl_copy_image_1d_to_1d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_2d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_3d;__cl_copy_image_2d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_image_3d_to_buffer;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_2d;__cl_copy_buffer_to_image_3d;__cl_fill_region_unalign;__cl_fill_region_align2;__cl_fill_region_align4;__cl_fill_region_align8_2;__cl_fill_region_align8_4;__cl_fill_region_align8_8;__cl_fill_region_align8_16;__cl_fill_region_align128;__cl_fill_image_1d;__cl_fill_image_1d_array;__cl_fill_image_2d;__cl_fill_image_2d_array;__cl_fill_image_3d;block_motion_estimate_intel;
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_khr_depth_images cl_khr_icd cl_intel_accelerator cl_intel_subgroups cl_intel_subgroups_short cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_intel_motion_estimation

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Intel Gen OCL Driver
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [Intel]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [Intel]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Intel Gen OCL Driver
    Device Name                                   Intel(R) HD Graphics IvyBridge M GT2

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.11
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

Comment: Have you checked `df -h`?

Comment: @doqtor of course I did and there was no problem. There is enough available space left in my hard disk.

Comment: it's related to the graphics card memory actually, maybe your desktop environment was taking too much VRAM? Try running from tty.